# Python webhelpers.html.tags with WSGI SCRIPT_NAME prefix

Tags: python, html, pylons, wsgi

I have a pylons web-app that generates links to controller actions using `routes.url_for`, and links to static files (CSS, javascript, images etc) using the functions defined in `webhelpers.html.tags`. This works fine while my web-app is hosted at the root of the server (i.e., the web-app is run from '/'). However, if I move the web-app, to be hosted at a different location, like '/foobar/', the `url_for` links work perfectly, but the functions under `webhelpers.html.tags` still generate links pointing to '/path/to/resource' rather than '/foobar/path/to/resource'.

My understanding is that WSGI defines an environment variable called `SCRIPT_NAME` that contains the path leading up to the application (so /foobar in this example). My guess is that `url_for` is paying attention to this environment variable and changing it's generated URLs accordingly.

*Is there a way to get the `webhelpers` module to do the same?*

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like the url_for is correctly returning the string with the URL you want.  But as far as I can see, you pass in a url string to the various webhelpers.

Are you doing something like this?

```
link_to('something', url(controller='path', action='to'))
```

Comment: This only works if you're linking to a controller. What parameters would you give to `url` (or `url_for`) if you're trying to link to an image, CSS file, or JS script?

Comment: url can take a static path, too like.. `url('/css/base.css')`

Comment: Thanks - that's the solution.